# C# How to await a method that returns Task<dynamic>?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, async-await, task

I have a method that is parsing the results from a JSON object. The method returns a Task object but when I run the code, I am getting the following error:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'
```

The object returned from the dynamic method is an array of objects of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary and System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair. Here is the code:

```
private static async Task<dynamic> GetReslutstAsync(string url)
    {
        WebRequest request;
        WebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "company");
            //request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            try
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var objects = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                return objects;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception occurs here:

```
private static async Task<dynamic> MakeRequest(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            return await GetReslutstAsync(url).Result;  //<---- This is where I get the error!
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I believe this has something to do with the fact that I am returning a dynamic type object. How can I get around this? I need to await this task inside the "MakeRequest" method so that it does not continue until the request is completed.

EDIT:

My "MakeRequest" method is in a loop like this:

```
while (true)
        {
            ClockTimer timer = new ClockTimer();
            timer.StartTimer(); //<---This does not stop untill 5 sec has passed
            MakeRequest("www.someurl.com"); //<--- This just skips into the next loop even if not complete.
        }
```

My issue is that `MakeRequest` is being run asynchronously so basically, it just skips over this and goes right into the next loop. I need "MakeRequest"  to HALT until the request is finished. I have tried removing all async/await keywords but this just results in "Result was not calculated".

Comment: I don't think you need the `.Result`

Comment: So what if I want to halt on the "GetReslutstAsync(url)" line of code until the the "result" is computed then continue by passing on that "dynamic" variable? Basically, I don't really want to do this asynchronously. This method gets called in a loop and I need to wait until the request is complete then move to the next loop. Should I just ditch the async/await all together?

Comment: I have tried `private static dynamic MakeRequest(string url)` and `GetReslutstAsync(url).Result;`, but this just runs the `GetResult()` method asynchronously and the loop continues even before the result is returned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
return await GetReslutstAsync(url);
```

You are not awaiting on the `dynamic`, only the task that returns a `dynamic`.

Comment: You were absolutely correct, after investigating this further, it turned out that my issue was actually with my Timer and NOT the GetResults method. My timer was assigning `timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);` handler on every loop. This was firing my Getresults multiple times. I was just looking in the wrong location for this bug. Thank you! I solved it by doing a `timer.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);` right before the timer exits.